# curl pull request error - fork_collab Fork collab can't be granted by someone without permission

Tags: bash, git, github, curl

I'm trying to automate github pull requests via bash script, specifically raising pull requests for forked branches. I've successfully done it for private repos, however it doesn't seem to work for public repos (see code below):

```
curl -H "Authorization: bearer <accesstoken>" -d '{"title":"SOMETITLE","base":"master","head":"'"someuser"':'"someForkedBranch"'","body":"some words to fill body."}' https://api.github.com/repos/<user-name>/<repo-name>/pulls
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this help? https://gist.github.com/mnem/1438396

Answer (score -1):

If this is for [*creating* a PR](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/pulls#create-a-pull-request), you would need a `-X POST` somewhere in your curl command, in order to *`POST`* the query for a new PR:

```sh
curl \
  -X POST \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/hello-world/pulls \
  -d '{"head":"head","base":"base"}'
```

Make sure also to use the right [oauth/PAT](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/other-authentication-methods#via-oauth-and-personal-access-tokens) or [SAML SSO](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/other-authentication-methods#authenticating-for-saml-sso):

```
curl -v -H "Authorization: token TOKEN" -X POST ...
```

Those token have just seen [a new format update](https://github.blog/2021-04-05-behind-githubs-new-authentication-token-formats/) (Apr. 2021) so you might need to regenerate one.

Comment: What error message do you see? Which OS and she'll are you using when typing that command?

Comment: The error message I see is the one in the OP. Using Gentoo, but I get this error on other distros as well.

Comment: @IThinkImOKAY Could you try again, with a new PAT (new token), to make sure to use their latest format? (Assuming you are the owner to the public repository you are pushing to)

Comment: Same thing with brand new API keys.